# If the allegations(made?) against him are found (to be?) true

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> If the allegations(made?) against him are found (to be?) true he could face rigorous imprisonment.

Is there any difference if I use or don't use *made* in the clause *allegations against* ?

Also when to use/not use *to be* after *found* in such  sentences ?

With these two doubts I'm able to form four different versions of above sentence but don't know which one is correct.

Comment: If the allegations (made) against him **were** (found to be) true he could face **a** rigorous imprisonment.

Comment: @Mv Log: At least in the US, use of subjunctive tense is largely considered optional at this point.  It sounds more educated, but isn't any more correct.

Comment: @Kirt Either **were\could** or **are\will or going to**, but not **are\could**.